# On click event in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a check box in my web site with the id 'checkbox1'. I use query to perform some commands when the user makes a selection like so:

```
$('#checkbox1').on('click', function(e) {
     //commands go here
});
```

In firefox the event handler kicks in when the user clicks on the checkbox arrow. I don't want that. I want it to respond to selections only. In safari I don't have this problem. The event doesn't kick in when I click the arrow, only when i make a selection. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about **[`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event, use it:

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function(e) {
     //commands go here
});
```